# Having trouble figuring out how to move only the "profile" nav link to the right side in the simplest way

Tags: html, css

[screenshot of my navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPiMa.png)

I am using bootstrap but can't figure out how to put the profile/login/logout links on the right for this app. I want to leave the Home About and Contact page on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the profile nav link to right by using ms-auto class in the profile nav link.

ms-auto is equivalent to margin-left: auto!important;

more about spacing bootstrap classes visit bootstrap 4 documentation